# connect between js file to phonegap java file

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

i'm developing in phonegap cordova version 3.5.0. i followed many guides and i cant'n build my one native code for phonegap.
my problems are:
where to locate the java files ?
what to write inside the config.xml ?
how the java script file can call to the java and get an answer ?

i'm put the java files into plugins folder then i write the js file and call him from index.html
the java file look like this:

```
package org.apache.cordova.plugin;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * This class echoes a string called from JavaScript.
 */
public class Echo extends CordovaPlugin {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("echo")) {
            String message = args.getString(0); 
            this.echo(message);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void echo(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) { 
            callbackContext.success(message);
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }
}
```

then the js look like this:

```
var HelloPlugin = { 
    callNativeFunction: function (success, fail, resultType) { 
      return cordova.exec( success, fail, 
                           "org.apache.cordova.plugin.Echo", 
                           "nativeAction", [resultType]); 
    } 
};


function callNativePlugin( returnSuccess ) { 
    HelloPlugin.callNativeFunction( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, returnSuccess ); 
} 
function nativePluginResultHandler (result) { 
   alert("SUCCESS: \r\n"+result ); 
} 
function nativePluginErrorHandler (error) { 
   alert("ERROR: \r\n"+error ); 
} 

callNativePlugin("avishay");
```

and the config xml:

```
<plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.Echo" />
```

i got an error "cordova is not defined"
why??? 
thanks a lot.

p.s
a good tutorial will be great.

Comment: the problem was "nativeAction" insted echo AND put cordova.js and cordova-plugin.js in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

Your js should be like :

```
var HelloPlugin = { 
callNativeFunction: function (success, fail, resultType) { 
  return cordova.exec( success, fail, 
                       "Echo", 
                       "echo", [resultType]); 
} 
};
```

No need to include your **full packege just include your Class Name** and also you String action is invalid one. Please follow below one.

Go through the following format

```
var version =  {
    createEvent: function(success, failure) {
        cordova.exec(
                success, // success callback function
                failure, // error callback function
            'JavaClassname', // mapped to our native Java class called "Echo"
            'GetVersionName', // with this action name(like "echo" our string action name in execute)
            []// here you need to pass params..
        );
    }
}
```